How to reload UI without restarting Blender
I'm writing addon which edits default UI.
To be specific - it works with VIEW3D_MT_mesh_add
The functionality I need goes beyond standard append/prepend
*hence this addon edits python code in UIspace_view3d.py

It works perfectly, though to apply changes to UI - I should restart Blender.
. How can I reload UI *without restarting Blender itself ?

bpy.ops.script.reload() should work.


It works perfectly. Huge thanks !
